# How do I use a custom palette in the legend bar?

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I have defined a custom gradient palette as follows:

```
ColorData[1];
new = {{"MyGradient", "", {}}, {"Gradients"}, 1, {0, 1}, {Darker[Blue], Blue, 
Cyan, Yellow, Orange, Red, Darker[Red]}, ""};
AppendTo[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes,new];
AppendTo[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNames, new[[1, 1]]];
```

And using the following I have potted some data.

```
plot2 = ListDensityPlot["file.dat", ColorFunction -> 
(ColorData["MyGradient"][Rescale[#, {0, 0.025}]] &),
PlotRange -> {{-radi2D, radi2D}, {-radi2D, radi2D}, {0,1}},
Frame->True,FrameLabel -> {LabelXX, LabelYY},LabelStyle -> 26,
PlotLabel -> Style[Row@{"t=",Time," ps"},FontSize -> 26],
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"MyGradient",{0,0.025}},
ColorFunctionScaling -> True, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26}, 
LegendMarkerSize -> {30,650}],
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
ClippingStyle -> Yellow, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 700];

Export[ToString[StringJoin[{"fotogramas.C_2D.",Time,".png"}]], plot2, "PNG"];
```

The problem is that I cannot get the legend bar filled with the cutom gradient as seen in the figure below.

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: `PlotLegend->BarLegend[{{Darker[Blue], Blue, Cyan, Yellow, Orange, Red, 
   Darker[Red]}, {0, 0.025}}]`

Comment: It worked perfectly and it was a simple solution! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Legended[
 ListDensityPlot[
  Table[y + Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, -4, 4, 0.2}, {y, -4, 4, 0.2}],
  DataRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["MyGradient"][Rescale[#, {-4, 4}]] &)],
 BarLegend[{ColorData["MyGradient"], {-4, 4}},
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26},
  LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 350}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I have been trying it and did not work... Maybe there is something wrong in my code... Thanks anyway!